# C# GetCommandLineArgs not parsing correctly or as expected

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, cmd

I have recently upgraded my version of Unity and launching my application with command line arguments does not work correctly if there is a space in the file path:

```
C:\>"D:\Builds\LiveBuilds\test folder\LIVE.exe" true test test
```

When entering the line above it would normally parse the path into one argument and then the following three into 1,2,3 indexes respectively. It appears that it is now ignoring the speech marks entirely.

When I did a build with the Unity version of 2019.2.13 this worked fine, it has only started occuring after updating to 2019.3.x

Here is how the arguments are getting parsed:

```
D:\Builds\LiveBuilds\test folder\LIVE.exe
```

[image]

Is this something to do with the .NET version being changed between Unity Versions or is there something I may not be aware of.

I am also using mono 4.x like I was previously as the API compatibility level.

**Edit 1:** I'd like to note that the quote marks are being put in by windows itself. I am just dragging the .exe in when testing. I would also like to mention that it is not just the command line this is an issue, it is in an external launcher application that uses process start functionality with the path of the downloaded application. This has been working with older versions of unity up to this point.

**Edit 2:** I downgraded the project to the previous version 2019.2.13 and it reads it fine. Is there a way to see what version of .net is being used or how Unity may deal with system code? Surely this doesn't make sense as its .net functionality?

**Edit 3:** Final Edit, it turns out it is an issue with Unity 2019.3 and will be fixed in a later build: [Unity Bug Report](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/system-dot-environment-dot-getcommandlineargs-method-returns-incorrect-values-when-application-name-contains-space-characters)

Comment: how are you testing the command arguments? it seems odd it would split the exe name up

Comment: `"D:\Builds\LiveBuilds\test folder\LIVE.exe"` is the command-line call to launch LIVE.exe - it is NOT a command-line argument.

Comment: Could you add you code please?

Comment: **C:\>"D:\Builds\LiveBuilds\test folder\LIVE.exe" true test test**

This line is how it appears in the cmd window. As you guys are saying its to launch Live.exe which it is doing.

`m_valuestoreForMenu.CommandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` 

this is where I get the string array of arguments. 

`Debug.LogError(m_valuestoreForMenu.CommandLineArgs[0] + " <<1  " + m_valuestoreForMenu.CommandLineArgs[1] + " <<2  " + m_valuestoreForMenu.CommandLineArgs[2] + " <<3   Is Guest? " + m_valuestoreForMenu.IsGuest);`

This is the debug line that is showing in red

Comment: @BugFinder Indeed it is. I got an old build (from Unity 2019.2.13) and that ran with the same command line string fine.

Comment: Just a thought.. Are you sure the quotes (speech marks) are 0x22?  Also, use the Process explorer to see what windows thinks was passed to the application.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm pretty sure, I will check the process explorer when I can thanks. The issue I have is that the exact same line on the old build works fine (accounting for .exe name). The reason we found this is because there is a 'launcher' program that does effectively the same thing using Process.Start that used to work and now does not on this build.

Comment: I looked in the process explorer and it is as it was before: `"D:\Builds\LiveBuilds\test folder\LIVE.exe" true test test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Unity 2019.3 and will be resolved in an newer version (2020)

Bug report can be found here https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/system-dot-environment-dot-getcommandlineargs-method-returns-incorrect-values-when-application-name-contains-space-characters